# serial ID on rows increment

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap pagination  in my react js   application now I want to show serial ID on rows increment to all the rows from 1 to 49th row. I write some code but it only shows 1 to 10 number and it loads again from 1 to 10 number when I go to next page and so on. my table show 10 records per page.

Code:

```
 onPageChange(page, sizePerPage) {
    console.log("page",page);
    console.log("sizePerPage",sizePerPage);

  }
```

Comment: Can you share some code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you've written your code but this is a basic way to think about pagination,

```js
function onPageChange(page, sizePerPage) {
    let startIndex = page * sizePerPage + 1;
    console.log("Page: ", page)
    console.log("startIndex", startIndex)
    for(i=0; i < sizePerPage; i++) {
      console.log(i+startIndex);
  
    }
    

  }
  
  
  let size = 10;
  let pages = 3;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    this.onPageChange(i, size);
  }
```